# why using <main> tag in html is considered good practice?

Tags: html, tags

I have seen people using `<main>` tag in an HTML document. Upon further research, using HTML-5 tags is considered best practice, but why?

Comment: Using HTML5 semantic tags would make your app SEO friendly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#accessibility_concerns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HTML-5 tags is considered best practice because one simple reason:

The browser knows what your element means. Because of that your SEO (Search engine optimalization) score gets better the more you use HTML-5 elements. One short example:

In this case the browser does not recognize the div is an header:

```
<div class='header'></div>
```

In this case the browser does recognize this is an header:

```
<header class='main_header'></header>
```

Because of this it is recommended to use HTML-5 tags.

More information about HTML-5 tags can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

More information about SEO can be found here: https://www.quanzhanketang.com/website/web_search.html